# PHP - How to create multidimentional JSON from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json, multidimensional-array, one-to-many

I need to create a multidimentional JSON from two MySQL tables. My code works, but I think it's very poorly written because it first concatenates DB values and then explodes the resulted string in PHP. There must be a better (and faster) way to do that.

I know similar questions have been asked many times, but I'm a noob I can't figure out how to apply the answers to my case.

So, I have the following MySQL tables:

```
    tbl1
-----------------------------
id| question   |correctanswer
-----------------------------
 1|'Yes or no?'|    'Yes'
 2|   'Who?'   |    'Peter'

    tbl2
-----------------------------
id|questionid| answeroptions
-----------------------------
1 |         1|'Yes'
2 |         1|'No'
3 |         2|'Peter'
4 |         2|'John'
5 |         2|'James'
6 |         2|'Jack'
```

I want to build JSON strings like that:

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "question":"Yes or no?",
    "correct_answer":"Yes",
    "answeroptions":[
                    "Yes",
                    "No"
                    ]
}
{
    "id":"2",
    "question":"Who?",
    "correct_answer":"Peter",
    "answeroptions":[
                    "Peter",
                    "John",
                    "James",
                    "Jack"
                    ]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT tabl1.id, tabl1.question, tabl1.correctanswer, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tbl2.answeroptions)
    FROM tabl1
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON (tabl1.id = tbl2.questionid)
    GROUP BY tabl1.id;";

$jsonarray = array();
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $jsonarray[$i]["topic"] = $row[0];
    $jsonarray[$i]["id"]=$row[1];
    $jsonarray[$i]["question"]=$row[2];
    $jsonarray[$i]["correct_answer"]=$row[3];
    $jsonarray[$i]["answeroptions"] = array();
    $jsonarray[$i]["answeroptions"] = explode(",",$row[4]);
    $i++;
}

for ($d=0; $d<count($jsonarray);$d++){
    echo json_encode($jsonarray[$d])."<br>";
}
```

UPD:
I made performance tests for three use cases:

1. Blake's suggestion
2. ded's suggestion
3. combined answeroptions into a new column in tbl1 to eliminate the second request and used ded's script modified accordingly.

I used a for loop * 100 times, and here are the results:

1. 0.16780591011047 sec
2. 0.0067291259765625 sec
3. 0.0005500316619873 sec

So, based on the performance, I come to a conclusion that using one-to-many relations in DB is not always the best option. For such simple tasks, all data can be stored in the same table.

Thanks you guys for your help!

Comment: I think you just need to remove your for-loop at the end of your code. Just have `echo json_encode($jsonarray[$d]);`, don't put it in a loop

Comment: @bassxzero thanks for the advice! Just for other guys who may also look into this: I needed to remove [$d], and it worked: `json_encode($jsonarray);`.

Comment: didn't notice that d, but yeah it needs to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT tabl1.id, tabl1.question, tabl1.correctanswer,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tbl2.answeroptions)
FROM tabl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON (tabl1.id = tbl2.questionid)
GROUP BY tabl1.id;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$jsonarray = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($jsonarray as $row) {
    $row["answeroptions"] = explode(",", $row["answeroptions"]);
}

echo json_encode($jsonarray)."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really be doing two queries for the best performance.  Try this code (untested)

```
# Question array holder
$questions = [];


# Loading the questions
$query = "  SELECT
                `id`,
                `question`,
                `correctanswer`
            FROM
                `tabl1`";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );


# Nothing to send
if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) == 0 ) {
    exit( '[]' );
}


# Adding questions to array
while( $question_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $question_data[ 'answeroptions' ] = [];
    $questions[ $question_data[ 'id' ] ] = $question_data;
}


# Loading the answer
$query = "  SELECT
                *
            FROM
                `tabl2`
            WHERE
                `questionid` IN (" . implode( ',', array_keys( $questions ) ) . ")";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );


# Adding answers to array
while( $answer_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $questions[ $answer_id[ 'questionid' ] ][ 'answeroptions' ][] = $answer_id[ 'answeroptions' ];
}


# Sending the questions
echo json_encode( array_values( $questions ) );
```

Comment: Thanks @blake-a-nichols, that works! Does it mean that there's no way to use one SQL query to achieve the same result?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  The two query method will always be quicker because you can index your tables properly and you are limiting the work mysql has to do to get your data.

Comment: @blake-a-nichols What if I drop the second table and just move all answeroptions to tbl1? I can create a varchar column containing comma-separated strings, and then just explode them to an array. Will it be faster than performing two queries? There will be 2 to 5 options, not more. (It will be be definitely easier for me to manage questions because I write them myself in Excel.) [edited: grammar]

Comment: I would keep them in separate tables, that is the primary purpose of a relational database.  Plus it gives your flexibility in the future if you decide to add some randomness to the "wrong" answers or if you create an admin page to add/edit questions and answers then you can reference everything by id.

Comment: Sounds good, but I think I still can do it while storing all the data in one table. Eliminating the second request, however, gives a huge performance increase, see my update to the post.

Comment: One table seems to be your choice, but keep in mind that GROUP_CONCAT has a max length of 1028 (default) and if your answer options start to get long your data will be truncated.